# C++/CX How to convert from IRandomAccessStream^ to bytes and back. (UWP)

Tags: c++, stream, uwp, buffer, c++-cx

So I have a stream, what I want to be able is to transfer it into unsigned char * bytes and back to usable stream.

This stream is image (it is binary if it is important?)

Basically what I am trying now is as follows:

```
IRandomAccessStream^ inputStream;

DataWriter^ dataWriter = ref new DataWriter(inputStream);
IBuffer^ buffer1 = dataWriter->DetachBuffer();
unsigned char * bytes = GetPointerToPixelData(buffer1);

DataWriter ^writer = ref new DataWriter();
writer->WriteBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<BYTE>(bytes, sizeof(bytes)));
task<DataWriterStoreOperation^>(writer->StoreAsync()).get();
task<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<bool>>(writer->FlushAsync()).get();

IBuffer ^buffer2 = writer->DetachBuffer();
IRandomAccessStream^ newStream;

task<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperationWithProgress<unsigned int, unsigned int>>(newStream->WriteAsync(buffer2)).get();
task<Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<bool>>(newStream->FlushAsync()).get();
UseNewStream(newStream)
```

I have added all of these task<...> because it is not working without them, and I am not sure how to make it work?
Function GetPointerToPixelData I found online and is following:

```
byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ buffer)
{
    // Cast to Object^, then to its underlying IInspectable interface.

    Object^ obj = buffer;
    ComPtr<IInspectable> insp(reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(obj));

    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
    ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    insp.As(&bufferByteAccess);

    // Retrieve the buffer data.

    byte* pixels = nullptr;
    bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels);

    return pixels;
}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to transfer the image stream to bytes, you need to read the stream by [`DataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader), not by [`DataWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datawriter) which is for write data. Secondly, the `DetachBuffer()` method is for "Detaches the buffer that is associated with the data reader", not read the buffer. Lastly, `DataReader` can directly read bytes by `ReadBytes(Byte[])` method. For example:

```
uint64 length = 0; 
BYTE *extracted;
void CleanImagetobyte::MainPage::btnconverttobyte_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    create_task(KnownFolders::GetFolderForUserAsync(nullptr /* current user */, KnownFolderId::PicturesLibrary))
        .then([this](StorageFolder^ picturesFolder)
    {
        return picturesFolder->GetFileAsync("B.jpg");
    }).then([this](task<StorageFile^> task)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile^ file = task.get();
            auto name = file->Name;
            return file->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read);
        }
        catch (Exception^ e)
        {
            // I/O errors are reported as exceptions.
        }
    }).then([this](task<IRandomAccessStream^> task)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream^  inputStream = task.get();
        length = inputStream->Size;
        IBuffer^ buffer = ref new Buffer(inputStream->Size);
        inputStream->ReadAsync(buffer, inputStream->Size, InputStreamOptions::None);
        DataReader^ reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);
        extracted = new BYTE[buffer->Length]; 
        reader->ReadBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<BYTE>(extracted, buffer->Length)); 
    });
} 


void CleanImagetobyte::MainPage::btnconvertback_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{ 
    create_task(KnownFolders::GetFolderForUserAsync(nullptr /* current user */, KnownFolderId::PicturesLibrary))
        .then([this](StorageFolder^ picturesFolder)
    {
        return picturesFolder->CreateFileAsync("newB.jpg", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting);
    }).then([this](task<StorageFile^> task)
    {
        StorageFile^ file = task.get();
        Array<byte>^ arr = ref new Array<byte>(extracted, length);
        FileIO::WriteBytesAsync(file, arr); 
    }); 
}
```

More details for read and write a file please reference [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).